# How to allow for plugins as separate crates

Tags: rust, plugins, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have a rust crate (that is published on crates.io).

The functionality that crate provides is also available as a command line utility,
that can be installed using `cargo install`.

This command line application accepts plugins using the following basic mechanism:

```rust
use libloading::Library;

pub trait Plugin {
    fn plugin_fn_1(&self);
    fn plugin_fn_2(&self);
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let plugin_paths: Vec<OsString> = Vec::new(); //???
    let mut plugin_registry = Vec::new();
    for path in plugin_paths {
        unsafe {
            let lib = Box::leak(Box::new(Library::new(path).unwrap()));
            let plugin_entry_point = lib
                .get::<libloading::Symbol<
                    unsafe extern "C" fn() -> &'static mut dyn Plugin,
                >>(b"plugin_entry_point")
                .unwrap();
            plugin_registry.push(plugin_entry_point());
        }
    }

    for plugin in &plugin_registry {
        plugin.plugin_fn_1();
    }
    // ...
}
```

I would like plugins to be individual crates (publishable on crates.io), and
installable using `cargo install`, **without** any additional user specified arguments.
How can the code above find the installed plugins (to fill the `plugin_paths` variable of the sample code above) in a cross platform way? (I only care about Linux, Mac and Windows).

Is there some established / conventional mechanism to do this?
I guess that either the plugins have to somehow register themselves during their own `cargo install`, or my binary has to scan some folder that it knows that the plugins will reside in.
I wouldn't mind either way, but I would like to avoid recursively searching through lots of directories every time the binary is launched.

Comment: Your code won't work for another reason: Rust's ABI is unspecified and unstable. `&dyn mut Plugin` is not FFI-safe. It is only guaranteed to work if you compile the plugins and the app with the exact same compiler version and flags, and even then I'm not sure.

Comment: @Chayim Friedman: for the sake of the question, assume that I have some versioning / compatability check in place (that uses the C ABI of course).

Comment: `cargo install` can only install binaries. So, not good enough for your use case. Probably, the best solution is to have the users download the repository, compile it, then copy the compiled artifact to some specific folder. You can provide a shell script to do that automatically.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: hm, that sucks. I'll leave this open in case anybody else has a better idea. Maybe the plugins can just pretend to be executables?

Comment: Or you could have the plugins _be_ executables that comunicate with the main process through some sort of IPC.

Comment: @Jmb: I have large amounts of data that plugins will be random accessing, so I'd rather not copy that across processes.

Comment: @ChrisB you can use shared memory to avoid copying the data (I believe that's how Gimp does it for example).